# Strange results using first_value and last_value on Oracle

Tags: oracle

```
select a.*, 
last_value(Status) over (partition by con_number, con_version order by CREATED_DATE asc) LTST_Status, 
first_value(Status) over (partition by con_number, con_version order by CREATED_DATE asc) FIRST_Status
from my_table a
```

which output me this result:

```
CON_NUMBER  CON_VERSION STATUS  CREATED_DATE    LTST_STATUS FIRST_Status
2786182955  1   異動手続完了  2014/6/19 14:16 異動手続完了  異動手続完了
2786182955  2   異動手続き中  2015/3/23 12:37 異動手続き中  異動手続き中
2786182955  2   異動手続完了  2015/4/3 16:05  異動手続完了  異動手続き中
```

My problem is when I use the 2 functions `last_value` and `first_value`.
The partition is made on CON_NUMBER and CON_VERSION, therefore, the ouput of LTST_STATUS should be 異動手続完了 and the outpu for FIRST_Status should be 異動手続き中 for the line where CON_VERSION = 2, isn't it?

Can you explain me this behavior ? Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the documentation 
- Please study this link - chapter under the heading "analytic clause / ROWS | RANGE " (at the end of document)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

You can find a short sentence there:

> **If you omit the windowing_clause entirely**, then the default is RANGE
>   BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

---

If you apply **ORDER BY** clause for an analytic function, for most functions a window specyfication can be used (there are some exceptions - depend on a concrete function, please refer to the documentation of the function) - and if you ommit the windows specyfication, then Oracle uses a default: 
`RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`

---

Please try this query and you will see a difference:

```
select a.*, 
last_value(Status) over (
         partition by con_number, con_version order by CREATED_DATE asc)
   LTST_Status,
last_value(Status) over (
         partition by con_number, con_version order by CREATED_DATE asc
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
   LTST_Status1, 
first_value(Status) over (
      partition by con_number, con_version order by CREATED_DATE asc)
   FIRST_Status
from my_table a
```